# Deep links handling of Marketing Cloud SDK in React Native

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, content-builder, react-native, deep-linking

SMC SDK for React Native: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk

I'm trying to use deep links with in-app messages but I'm not getting them to work. After receiving the in-app message, I press a button that has a deep link configured on the Marketing Cloud and the message gets simply closes. The expected result is to be redirected to a screen but it doesn't redirect anywhere in the app.

I wonder if anyone was able to configure deep links with in-app messages in React Native.

Is there any extra configuration needed that is missing in the MarketingCloud SDK
documentation for React Native?

Deep links are configured correctly on Android and iOS as they were previously independently tested.

---

More info:

I created the in-app message in the content builder section. The in-app message has two buttons that contain deep links of the form `appschema://screen` which after pressing them should redirect to a screen. This event should be detected with the React Native Linking API, that is, at the JavaScript level, but no event is detected, even in native code.

Following you can find the code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "ReactNativeConfig.h"
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
#import "RNSplashScreen.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import <MarketingCloudSDK/MarketingCloudSDK.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"appname"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  [FIRApp configure];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [RNSplashScreen showSplash:@"LaunchScreen" inRootView:rootView];
  
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;
  
  

  // Configure the Salesforce Marketing Cloud SDK
  MarketingCloudSDKConfigBuilder *mcsdkBuilder = [MarketingCloudSDKConfigBuilder new];
    [mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setApplicationId:[ReactNativeConfig envFor:@"MC_APP_ID"]];
    [mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setAccessToken:[ReactNativeConfig envFor:@"MC_ACCESS_TOKEN"]];
    [mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setAnalyticsEnabled:@(YES)];
    [mcsdkBuilder sfmc_setMarketingCloudServerUrl:[ReactNativeConfig envFor:@"MC_APP_SERVER_URL"]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success =
        [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_configureWithDictionary:[mcsdkBuilder sfmc_build]
                                                                   error:&error];
  
  if (success == YES) {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           if (@available(iOS 10, *)) {
               // set the UNUserNotificationCenter delegate - the delegate must be set here in
               // didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
               [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
               [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

               [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
                   requestAuthorizationWithOptions:UNAuthorizationOptionAlert |
                                                   UNAuthorizationOptionSound |
                                                   UNAuthorizationOptionBadge
                                 completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *_Nullable error) {
                                   if (error == nil) {
                                       if (granted == YES) {
                                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                          });
                                       }
                                   }
                                 }];
           } else {
 #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 100000
               UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings
                   settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound |
                                    UIUserNotificationTypeAlert
                         categories:nil];
               [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
 #endif
               [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
           }
         });
     } else {
         //  MarketingCloudSDK sfmc_configure failed
         os_log_debug(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "MarketingCloudSDK sfmc_configure failed with error = %@",
                      error);
     }

  return YES;
}

- (void)sfmc_handleURL:(NSURL *)url type:(NSString *)type {
  NSLog(@"Handling open direct url coming from Marketing Cloud");
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionary];
  [appDelegate application:[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:dict];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
  [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_setDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
  [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_setNotificationUserInfo:userInfo];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// IOS 10+ Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
  [[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_setNotificationRequest:response.notification.request];
  completionHandler();
}
// IOS 4-10 Required for the localNotification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  os_log_debug(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "url = %@", url);
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

@end
```

React Native side:

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
  // This is not executed
  // Handle url;
});

Linking.addEventListener('url', ({ url }) => {
  // This is not executed
  // Handle url;
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Post code.  URL Handling definitely works.

Comment: @BillMote I just added the `AppDelegate.m` file, hope this can help me to figure out what is going on

Comment: Do you have an open support case @RodrigoViera?

Comment: @BillMote No I don't. I'm new working with the Salesforce Marketing Cloud SDK. The Push notifications works well so the SDK is correctly integrated. What is not working is the URL handling for the deep links contained within the in-app messages that are sent from the journey builder. So if you can point me what should I do, would be great. The above code shows the entire AppDelegate.m file content. I am missing something there??? Thanks

Comment: I've asked the iOS team to look into it, but you should always start with a support case.  Any help you get "here" is voluntary.

Comment: @BillMote do you receive any news from the iOS team?

Comment: Did you open a support case?

Comment: @BillMote Yes. Case #42247559

Comment: Please have them at-mention me.

Comment: Thank you @RodrigoViera.  Support has reached out.  My team will be looking into your issue shortly.

Comment: hi, I have the same issue, did you figure it out? Could you please let me know how it was resolved? thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dody open a support case.